# Issue in updating table

Tags: java

I am receiving below error in my program because of which my table is not getting updated. can anyone help me with it :-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
May 22, 2022 10:22:18 PM org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.TempFileManager <clinit>
INFO: TempFileManager::unable to delete /tmp/axis2-tmp-7142968763938811683.tmp
May 22, 2022 10:22:18 PM org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.TempFileManager <clinit>
INFO: TempFileManager::unable to delete /tmp/axis2-tmp-1931726811019904379.tmp
May 22, 2022 10:22:18 PM org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.TempFileManager <clinit>
INFO: TempFileManager::unable to delete /tmp/axis2-tmp-804075563315894510.tmp
```

Comment: The first 2 are warnings related to your log4j configuration and very likely not the reason your tables aren't updated. The others are info messages and also very likely not a real issue. The logging issue might be preventing you from seeing the actual issue but without more information we can't help. Please fix the logging issue or ask another question about it first then post any messages and code related to updating your tables. Oh and btw: please read [ask] _first_.

Comment: If you believe the inability to delete temp files is the reason, have you checked the paths mentioned in the logs? Do the files exist? Who is the owner? What are the permissions?